# how to change elements order with bootstrap and breakpoints

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to make this happen with bootstrap?
I tried with pull-right/push-left, but the bottom div (light blue) is in one line with the yellow div and not at the top.

[image]

```
<div class='col-xs-12'>1</div>
<div class='col-xs-12'>2</div>
<div class='col-xs-12'>3</div>
```

Comment: If the answer worked for you, you should accept it by clicking on the check mark below the answer's up/down vote. This alerts readers to what the questioner found to be useful. (Anyone can give an up or down vote.) It also enhances the answers reputation.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-xs-6'>
     <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-12'>1</div>
        <div class='col-xs-12'>2</div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class='col-xs-6'>3</div>
</div>
```

You'll need to make a custom media query to handle the break at 320px.

http://codepen.io/tsneville/pen/bpWNYo